# Word wrap when printing a file with hardcopy

Tags: printing

While in ViM I can set the `linebreak` option to make a long line wrap at the end of the window avoiding a word to be split in two pieces, but I cannot find an equivalent option while printing a file with `:hardcopy` or `:hardcopy > out.ps` (there is the wrap option while setting `printoptions`, but, if set, it can split a word in two parts). Is there an equivalent option of `linebreak` while printing out the file with `:hardcopy`?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Writing or code? Either way, I’d say you should either hardwrap or use a typesetting system à la TeX that can do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is convert to HTML and print from the browser with `:TOhtml`